# conditions to move out off beta state

Tags: discussion

I understand beta version is ment to find out if this site is worth casting.

But what are the main points that will be evaluated to decide wether or not this site will :

1. go to public beta version
2. go live

And how will/are they evaluated?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure when public beta starts, somewhere I read 10 days after private beta started but I don't know the conditions for public beta.

For going live there is a statistic on the [area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla). It will be at least 90 days in public beta and maximum 2 years, then I think it will be deleted?

[Eartchsience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) is 6 days ahead and there public beta started 6 days after private beta see there [area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science)

Comment: The metrics on the area51 page will also be available on the main site too at times. Those are the big metrics, so following their advice is good. It is pretty straightforwad: ask lots of questions, provide lots of answers.

Comment: Thanks for those links, I didn't think of going back to area51 to find those metrics. But in those metrics there is nothing about "question quality" is it a criteria or does it not matter as long as those metrics are at least average?

Comment: 6 days seems very short!? The [Software Recommendations site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) was in Private Beta for quite a while longer than that - even though it seemed very active. In fact, [they asked for an extension](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/308/an-odd-request-can-we-have-another-week-in-private-beta/399).